# Trying to format Google App Engine DateTimeProperty for template

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm using the Tornado framework (Python) on GAE.  I'm still kind of new to the whole MVC concept and GAE... and having a dang of a time trying to figure out how to do this.

I have a table (model) Post with the fields user, text, creation_date.

I pull all the posts in the code and then send it to the template.  I want to format the creation_date field so it's formatted a bit nicer.  Something like M-d-Y.  I know I use strptime or strftime to format the creation_date.  But I'm not sure how to do it before I send posts to the template.

Here is what I use to get the posts and send it to the template...

```
class HomeHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        posts = Post.all()
        posts.order("-creation_date")
        self.render('home.html', posts=posts)
```

UPDATE:

```
posts = Post.all().order("-creation_date").fetch(50)
posts = [{'text': post.text} for post in posts]
for post in posts:
        print post.text
```

Error message I get:

> AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'text'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using Tornado's [template](http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation#templates) module, it includes the datetime module.  I have not used Tornado's template module, but you should be able to use:

```
entity.datetime_property.strftime('%m-%d-%y')
```

If you want to process your models before sending them to the template try something like:

```
class HomeHandler(BaseHandler):
  def get(self):
    posts = Post.all().order("-creation_date").fetch(50)
    posts = [{'author': post.author,
              'subject': post.subject,
              'date': post.date} for post in posts]
    self.render('home.html', posts=posts)
```

Within your template posts will be a list of dictionaries containing the fields author, subject, and date.

Use fetch to limit the number of posts you return; it will improve performance by grabbing (up to) 50 entities at once instead of grabbing them in smaller batches.

Comment: Doh, I lied!  I thought I got the second part to work, but I was wrong.  I'm getting "AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'text'"

Comment: Can you post the actual code you used in both the handler and the template?

Comment: Sorry, I'm still kinda a newbie to this site... I tried to put the code in the comment.  I just updated the original post with some bare bones version of the problem.

Comment: Okay.  That prints it out.  Now I gotta figure out how to use post['text'] in the template.  It's still all pretty confusing to me though.  When I do posts = Post.all(), and I type "print posts", I get "<google.appengine.ext.db.Query object at 0x4748dd0>".  But when I cycle through it in a loop, "print post.text" works.  And then when I add the line of code you gave me, I can do "print posts" and it prints out dictionary within dictionary?

Comment: The code I gave you will let you processes the posts in your handler before sending them to a template.  In this case it is done using a list comprehension (http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).  Here is the confusing part, I think to access the dictionary element *within a django template* you use "dot notation, ie dictionary.element.  If you just want to loop over all of the entities in your template, just omit the list comprehension (the posts = [...] part).